# swift - Show push notification banner wherever user is in app

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3

I'm trying to show a banner when a user get's a push notification no matter which view controller the user is currently looking at.

The most scalable way that I could think of is creating a `BannerController` class that would have something like this

```
 if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {


                window.addSubview(bannerView)
            }
```

So I would create a `BannerController` object in each of my view controllers and subscribe become it's delegate.

Then, when the user received a push notification... post a notification to my `BannerController` which would then delegate the action of showing it.

This doesn't seem perfect since I'm going to have to create a `BannerController` object in each view controller that I want to display it in... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the presented view controllers and then present a modal view controller over the top one.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(
    title: "Alert", 
    message: "Message", 
    preferredStyle: .alert
)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(...))

if let window = window, var currentVC = window.rootViewController {
    while currentVC.presentedViewController != nil
        currentVC = currentVC.presentedViewController!
    }
    currentVC.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```

In this example I'm using a UIAlertController, but you could switch that to something matching your description of alert. There are a lot of open source ones (https://github.com/bryx-inc/BRYXBanner), or you could write your own.

Comment: I'm definitely going to create my own but I think making my BannerController a static method and doing what you mentioned might be my solution. I'll let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and created my own library for it: [MDNotificationView](https://github.com/moritzdietsche/mdnotificationview)

It uses your approach to show the banner on top of all views. You could do this directly from your `AppDelegate` too.

```
let view = MDNotificationExpandedImageLayoutView()
view.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Face")      
view.titleLabel.text = "New message from someone"
view.textLabel.text = "Hello."

// You can pass any UIView here.
let notificationView = MDNotificationView(view: view)
notificationView.delegate = self
notificationView.show()

// MARK: - Notification View Delegate

func notificationDidShow(notificationView: MDNotificationView) {
    // Hide the notification view automatically after 5 seconds.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        notificationView.hide()
    }
}
```

Feel free to borrow from the code or ask questions.

Comment: Please provide me source code of MDNotificationView